# Как в bootstrap carousel убрать индикаторы, а именно кружки, а текст оставить?

Tags: bootstrap, css

Хочу избавиться от кружков и заменить их текстом. При:

```
.carousel-indicators li {
     display: none;
}
```

[image: Вот, кружок]

Удаляется и текст. Логично. Но как убрать? Ищу уже вот столько в интернете, но найти не могу

Comment: Посмотрел последние вопросы... Разработка JS карусели по принципу "С мира по нитке".

Может быстрее и проще будет самому нормально разобраться в данном вопросе? Нет, если кто желает помогать - пожалуйста, Я не протестую. Про100 лично для Вас будет проще самостоятельно сделать, чем каждый шаг вытягивать из сообщества.

Comment: Форум для того, чтобы спросить то, чего не знаешь и не можешь в другом месте найти. Нет? Я только приступил к работе с bootstrap и знаю, что много вопросов задаю. Но я учусь работать с ним, что поделаешь. Я задал вопрос. Можете и не ответить и даже не переходить по ссылке. Всего хорошего. @uzumaxy

Comment: Вопросы на форумах задают для какой цели? Научиться, продвинуться в реализации проекта и т.п. Так вот, лично Я считаю, что Вам вопросы задавать при малейшей трудности не нужно. Вы пока ставили карусель 3 вопроса на хешкод написали. Таким путем Вы ничего не научитесь.

Я тоже своего рода совет даю, то, что он Вам не нравиться - не повод сердиться ;)

Comment: @uzumaxy я понимаю Вас. Но я не могу найти в интернете как их убрать. Я 30 минут как ищу. Нету нигде. Вот и задаю.

@Deonis нет, там как бы "Текст <индикатор>" идет. Я хочу только Текст оставить

Comment: Этот *<индикатор>* - это что? Какой-то элемент, или псевдоэлемент, или это бэкграундом что-то светится? Это чудо, вообще, где-то посмотреть можно?

Comment: .carousel-indicators li {
         display: inline-block;
         width: 10px;
         height: 10px;
         margin: 1px;
         text-indent: -999px;
         cursor: pointer;
         background-color: #000 \9;
         background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
         border: 1px solid #ffffff;
         border-radius: 10px;
     }

Comment: Вот и попробуйте убрать background-color или же установить его прозрачным.

    background-color: transparent ;

Comment: Значит не то смотрели. Гляньте в стилях - есть там что-то вроде:

    .carousel-indicators li::before {}
    .carousel-indicators li::after {}

Comment: Покажите код карусели. Полностью. На jsfiddle или внешним html файлом.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/C72rj/

Comment: Предоставленный вами пример нерабочий. Вы не подключили bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Решение](http://jsfiddle.net/mUreD/). Необходимо было убрать ol.carousel-indicators

Answer (score 0):

Для ul, в котором находятся твои пункты добавь стиль
ul{
     list-style: none;
}

Comment: [Не поможет][1]

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/4a39R/1/